# is [0-9a-fA-F] the same as [0-9a-f-A-F]?

Tags: regex, grep

Are these two equivalent? `[0-9a-fA-F]` and `[0-9a-f-A-F]`

I've been trying these two regexes with egrep in some texts and they seem to be equivalent.
Is there a case they won't be return same results?

Also, in the second expression, what is the meaning of the second `-` and why would I need it? I am bit confused with these simple examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second expression also matches a dash as well as hexadecimals

**Edit** in `egrep`, which is what you're using the second one is in fact invalid:

```
# echo "12345678" | egrep '^[0-9a-f-A-F]+$'
egrep: Invalid range end
```

The correct expression for the second is by ending with a dash:

```
[0-9a-fA-F-]
```

Comment: That's one interpretation, but the expression is really ambiguous; you have not tagged this question to specify any particular regex dialect, so it might also be "yeah, in practice they are equivalent", or "we don't know either".

Comment: @tripleee right, in JavaScript it works like that, but he's using `egrep` now that I read his question again ... and that just dun work ;-)

Comment: This is weird ... I just tried that and I don't get an error, I get: `12345678`

Comment: @Jack What version of egrep are you using?

Comment: @nacho4d I don't think the version really matters, as your expression is just wrong ;-) but fwiw i'm using 2.5.1 and 2.5.4

Comment: Ohh!, the correct expression explains everything! Thanks for making this very clear. BTW, I got the example from "Mastering Regular Expression" but the first edition :)

Answer (score 8):

No, these two regex are not equal. In the second one you add character '-'

Answer (score 3):

`[0-9a-f-A-F]` = `[0-9a-fA-F]` + `-`